# Zooming image on QGraphicsScene with mouse wheel in pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a code that opens the video, extracts the first frame from it, saves as an image, opens the image and displays it on QGraphicsScene. And I have a question - how can I zoom in and out an image with the mouse wheel?

Code OFT_MainWindow

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(862, 710)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.centralwidget)
        self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 90, 841, 571))
        self.graphicsView.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")
        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 670, 81, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.buttonBox.setFont(font)
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(760, 10, 91, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 731, 31))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 670, 331, 31))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 841, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Browse"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Highlight the field area"))
```

Main code

```
import OFT_MainWindow 
import sys
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageQt, ImageEnhance
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.Qt import Qt

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_() 
    
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, OFT_MainWindow.Ui_MainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)  
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.browse_file) 
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.imageFrame)
        self.buttonBox.clicked.connect(self.click_OK)
        self.ellipseItem = None
        
###################################################################################    

    def browse_file(self):
        self.lineEdit.clear() 
        file = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Choose video OFT")
        file = str(file[0])
        if file: 
            self.lineEdit.setText(file) 

###################################################################################    

    def imageFrame(self): 
        file = self.lineEdit.text() 
        vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(file)
        success, image = vidcap.read()
        cv2.imwrite("frame.jpg", image)
        pic = str("frame.jpg")
        scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self) 
        self.image = QPixmap(pic) 
        item = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem(self.image)
        scene.addItem(item) 
        view = self.graphicsView.setScene(scene) 
        scene.installEventFilter(self)
        
    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.GraphicsSceneMousePress:
            for item in self.graphicsView.scene().items(event.scenePos()):
                if isinstance(item, QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem):
                    self.reference = item
                    self.ellipseItem = QtWidgets.QGraphicsEllipseItem(item)
                    self.ellipseItem.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 0, 75))
                    self.start = item.mapFromScene(event.scenePos())
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.GraphicsSceneMouseMove and self.ellipseItem:
            end = self.reference.mapFromScene(event.scenePos())
            self.ellipseItem.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
            self.ellipseItem.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
            self.ellipseItem.setRect(QtCore.QRectF(self.start, end))
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.GraphicsSceneMouseRelease and self.ellipseItem:
            self.ellipseItem = None
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(app.deleteLater)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I tried to implement it with wheelEvent but I couldn't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install an event filter to the graphics view's [`viewport()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#viewport), and check for `Wheel` events.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, OFT_MainWindow.Ui_MainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # ...
        self.graphicsView.viewport().installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if (source == self.graphicsView.viewport() and 
            event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Wheel):
                if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
                    scale = 1.25
                else:
                    scale = .8
                self.graphicsView.scale(scale, scale)
                # do not propagate the event to the scroll area scrollbars
                return True
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.GraphicsSceneMousePress:
            # ...
        return super().eventFilter(source,event)
```

Consider that wheel events are also intercepted for scrolling, so you should probably use a modifier for zooming; for example, using ctrl+wheel:

```
    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if (source == self.graphicsView.viewport() and 
             event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Wheel and
             event.modifiers() == QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier):
                 # ...
```